# Media Player is a null object, when made from an activity which was launched from a BroadCastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a MediaPlayer from a activity, which was OPENED BY A BROADCAST RECEIVER. This works fine, if I play an internal file from the R.raw folder. But if I try to access a Mp3 file via a URI, it doesn't work anymore.

```
public class AlarmScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_screen);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    startMusic();
    }

private void startMusic() {
    String stringUri = element.getUri();

    if (!(stringUri.equals(""))){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

The Error I get looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

I also tried to make the Media Player the following way, but it led to the same result:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }, 300);
```

I guess that the problem lies somewhere within the permissions, because as far as I know the BroadCastReceivers don't have the same permissions as the normal apps. 
If you need more code, please let me know.

EDIT:

I have narrowed down the problem by making the following test-project:
Here 2 Uris are created. For Uri1, I use the data from the chooser. For Uri2 I use the Uri-String from a previous round. Then these Uris are played in the start(). If I play Uri1, it works always. But if I play Uri2, it only works if Uri1 is equal to Uri2. This is only the case if the same music-file is chosen in the chooser again, as in the round where I originally copied Uri2.

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is there another way, to access music-files from your device?

```
private void play(){
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uri2 = Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A17207");
    uri1 = data.getData();

    String str = uri.toString();

}

private void start(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose:"), 1);
}
```

Comment: Probably your `Uri` is a `null` and that is why you are getting `null pointer exception`. If you didn't manage permission for accessing phone storage and uri exposed exception that could be some of the reasons why `Uri` is a `null` when you try to play it.

Comment: @Yupi The Uri is working fine. This should not be the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is that whole code you have?

Comment: @Yupi no thats just a small fraction. But there is no more code about the MediaPlayer. Is something missng?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because of permissions.

Try to add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your manifest.

Something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.snazzyapp">
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     ...
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem. I still get the null point exeption. Do you have any other ideas? In the documentation, they mention Restricting Broadcast with Permission, but I don't understand it. Might this be the problem? here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#restrict-broadcasts-permissions)

Comment: I saw the link, but i thik thats not the problem. I think the problem could be the path to the file, where is saved the File?.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I tried to access a music file via an Uri in a normal activity and it didn't work aswell. Unfortunately I still can't fix my problem, but I have added an "edit" in my post, where I described how I isolated the code and what results I got. It would be really kind if you could take a look at it.